# detect is the last row in column is changed and fire event

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to trigger an event if the user starts to type anything in the last empty cell in column B.
I have the code bellow so far but have a mismatch for the range and not sure how to correct it.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim LastNonEmptyRow, LastRow, LastEmptyRow, LastValue As Long

LastNonEmptyRow = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'finds the last NON-EMPTY Row in Columnt B

LastEmptyRow = LastNonEmptyRow + 1' 
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range(LastEmptyRow)) Is Nothing Then ' LastEmptyRow needs to be as Range
        MsgBox "You entered something in last empty row in column B!"
        '...code to execute when data is entered in the last empty column

   End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify your range correctly.  Change from this:

```
Range(LastEmptyRow)
```

To this:

```
Range("B" & LastEmptyRow)
```

**EDIT:**

Taking the above into account along with your additional comments, the code ends up like this:

```
Private oldValue As String

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
   oldValue = Target.Value
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   Dim LastNonEmptyRow As Long
   Dim LastRow As Long
   Dim LastEmptyRow As Long
   Dim LastValue As Long

   If oldValue <> "" Then Exit Sub

   LastNonEmptyRow = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'finds the last NON-EMPTY Row in Columnt B
   LastEmptyRow = LastNonEmptyRow + 1

   If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B" & LastNonEmptyRow)) Is Nothing Then ' LastEmptyRow needs to be as Range
      MsgBox "You entered something in last empty row in column B - " & LastNonEmptyRow
      '...code to execute when data is entered in the last empty column
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Brian, thank you for quick comment. your method does not give Range issue anymore, but the code MsgBox does not fire. I placed  If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B" & LastEmptyRow)) Is Nothing Then ' LastEmptyRow needs to be as Range
        MsgBox "You entered something in last empty row in column B!" and the MsgBox does not fire, however if I place  If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B" & LastNonEmptyRow)) Is Nothing Then ' LastEmptyRow needs to be as Range the code fires for the last NON-EMPTY and for last Empty cell in column B

Comment: Hi Brian, thank you for quick comment. your method does not give Range issue anymore, but the code MsgBox does not fire. I placed `If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B" & LastEmptyRow)) Is Nothing Then ' LastEmptyRow needs to be as Range MsgBox "You entered something in last empty row in column B!" `and the MsgBox does not fire, however if I place `If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B" & LastNonEmptyRow)) Is Nothing Then ` code fires for last non-empty and empty cell

Comment: By the time the Change event fires the cell that was empty is no longer empty.  When I change your code to use the LastNonEmptyRow it works how I think you want it to work.  I only get 1 event and its for the row I just changed.  The row which had been empty prior to me modifying it.

Comment: yes, the code works if I use LastNonEmptyRow for last empty row, but it also fires if last non-empty row is modified, which I do not need.

Comment: You will need to determine if the previous value of the cell is null.  Please look at my updated code.